# Linking HTML to CSS

Tags: html, css

Ok im trying to link my index.html to mystylesheet.css but is isn't working? It works perfectly on CodeAcademy but doesnt seem to work when I run it in chrome. I'm using Notepad++ by the way. When I say isn't working, i mean that the styles in the css aren't coming up, like the background colour for example. here it all is, is there anything im doing wrong?

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="mystylesheet" href="mystylesheet.css"/>
<title>A$AP World</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Please agree with the terms&conditions before entering.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**mystylesheet.css**

```
body {
background-color: black;
}

p{
color:red;
}

img {
display: block;
height: 100px;
width: 300px;
margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the console to see if there are any errors and the path to your stylesheet is correct and loading?

Comment: can you provide your folder structure?

Comment: the path to your mystylesheet.css is probably wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `rel` attribute should be `rel="stylesheet"`:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="mystylesheet.css"/>
```

[SitePoint explains it nicely](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/link/rel):

> The rel attribute defines the relationship that the linked resource has to the document from which it’s referenced. In most cases, this resource will simply be "stylesheet", which means, not surprisingly, “the referenced document is a style sheet.”

Answer (score 3):

Change the `rel` attribute value, to be `rel="stylesheet"`

Change this line

```
<link type="text/css" rel="mystylesheet" href="mystylesheet.css"/>
```

to be

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="mystylesheet.css"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystylesheet.css">
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
rel="stylesheet"
```

instead of

```
rel="mystylesheet"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystylesheet.css" />
```

As you're using an HTML5 doctype, you can also leave off the type declaration.